# using sdkImages not found WP 8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to implement some pinch&zoom and I need to include the `sdkImages.Resources`. The compiler says that:

> Error 2   The type or namespace name 'sdkImages' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have the references:

> Windows Phone and the .NET for Windows Phone.

I downloaded a Sample from Windows Phone Dec Center and there is no problems... Can someone to expplain me what I should include or add to my project?

Comment: Which sample you have downloaded from MSDN ? Can you mention it ?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your source code could help us to provide an answer.

Anyway, is your app namespace "sdkImages"?
Are you trying to reference your App Resources (i.e. the auto-built "AppResources.Designer.cs" AppResources wrapper) with a different/wrong namespace?

Is there a chance you started from the "Image Recipes" example from http://www.getcodesamples.com/ and changed your app namespace (but not the Resources namespace)?

Try to rename "sdkImages.Resources" to ".Resources" and see if it can compile now.